# What numerical notation is this?

Tags: notation

What type of numerical notation is this and how does it convert to regular notation?
Example: 4.09383762e367

Comment: Scientific notation, specifically [E-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)  $4.09383762e367=4.09383762\cdot 10^{367}$

Comment: If you wanted to write it out in standard notation, you would need to move the decimal point over to the right 367 times, adding zeros as needed. In standard notation, it is: 40938376200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.0

Answer (score 2):

$4.09383762e367 = 4.09383762 \cdot 10^{367}$. This notation is called "E-notatation" and is often used in calculators to shorten the expressions.